# Community Users not able to generate PDF - getContentAsPdf() not working

Tags: apex, community, getcontentaspdf

I have looked at numerous articles but did not find a solution for Community Users and PDF creation. The idea is to auto-create a PDF when a Community user clicks on a checkbox. This is working for internal users but not for external users. And yes, I am changing the base URL based on internal/external users.

Note, the pdf is created asynchronously and I have verified the "networkId" too.

Trigger:

```
trigger CreatePDF on My_Object__c (after insert, after update) {

String sObjectAPIName = 'My_Object__c';

// Create and email PDF as per the PDF Rules
CreatePDFHelper.createPDF();
```

}

Apex Class:

```
    global with sharing class CreatePDFHelper implements System.Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {

static boolean isCommunityUser = true;
String networkId;

global CreatePDFHelper(){}

global CreatePDFHelper (String networkId) {
    this.networkId = networkId;
}

public static void createPDF() {

    // Get the Network Id for communities user
    String networkId = Network.getNetworkId();
    system.debug('NetworkId ' + networkId);

    //Create PDF and store as attachment
    System.enqueueJob(new CreatePDFHelper(networkId));
}  


//PDF Rules - Create Files and send email. Now with mass email feature
global void execute(QueueableContext context) {
    ContentVersion document = createDocument(networkId);
}


//Create ContentVersion/File 
public static ContentVersion createDocument(String networkId) {

    String sObjId = 'a2p9X0000000000000';
    String URL = '/apex/TestPDF';
    //Get the URL from the custom settings
    if (isCommunityUser) {
        URL = 'https://myDomain--playground.sandbox.my.site.com/mySite' + URL;
    } 
    
    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference(URL);
    //Blob body = pageRef.getContentAsPdf();
    Blob body = blob.valueOf('This is a test document generated from the apex class');
    system.debug('body ' + body);
    
    ContentVersion document = getDocument(sObjId, 'TestDocument.pdf', body, networkId);
    system.debug('document ' + document);
    Insert document;

    return document;
} 

public static ContentVersion getDocument(String locationId, String fileName, Blob body, String networkId) {

    ContentVersion document = new ContentVersion( 
        ContentLocation = 'S',
        PathOnClient = fileName,
        Title = fileName, 
        VersionData = body
    );

    if(String.isNotBlank(locationId)) {
        document.FirstPublishLocationId = locationId;
    }
            
    if(String.isNotBlank(networkId)) {
        document.put('NetworkId', networkId);
    }

    system.debug('document ' + document);
    return document;
}
```

}

Visualforce page

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" title="Test PDF Document" cache="true" renderAs="pdf" applyHtmlTag="false">

This is a test document generated from the VF page
```

</apex:page>

Internal Link: https://myDomain--playground--c.sandbox.vf.force.com/apex/TestPDF

External Link: https://myDomain--playground.sandbox.my.site.com/mySite/apex/TestPDF

To find the root cause, I also tried generate a dummy blob using below code

```
Blob body = blob.valueOf('This is a test document generated from the apex class');
```

Then the pdf is created and stored as a file, but opening the PDF shows below message.

[image]

Comment: What do debug logs say? Any exceptions there?

Comment: Does the portal user's profile have the 'View Content in Portal' permission?

Comment: The dummy blob is not a valid PDF format, it's just you text vale that has been blobbed.  you need to use GetContentAsPdf.

Comment: @kurunve , nothing in the debug logs
- Vince, not checked that permission,  will look into it.
- DavidCheng, thank you for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for the comments. I finally got it to work using below instead of dynamically changing the URL based on internal vs external user.

```
PageReference pageRef = Page.TestPDF;
pageRef.getParameters().put('id', sObjId);
pageRef.getParameters().put('templateId', templateId);
```

Even better because I do not have do additional query to get the correct base url and worry about multiple communities.